# Enum class body feature in Java 1.6

Tags: java, enums

```
enum CoffeeSize{               
      BIG(8),   
      HUGE(10),   
      OVERWHELMING(16) {   

       public String getLidCode(){   
            return "A";   
       }   
      };   

    private int ounces;   

    public int getOunces(){   
         return ounces;   
    }    

    CoffeeSize(int ounces){   
        this.ounces = ounces;   
    }   

    public String getLidCode(){   
            return "B";   
    }   
}
```

This is a SCJP 1.6 question from K&B 6 book.
This is an example of Constant Specific Class Body as a feature of SCJP 6. How do I execute this and see the resultant output?

I have 2 questions:

1. What does my Java main method look like ?Please help me to execute this partial code. I'm unable to understand how the output behaves.
2. How does the `getLidCode()` method work in this class body in Java 1.6 ?

Comment: "Execute" what? It's an enum. `CoffeeSize.BIG.getOunces()`

Comment: can i know where i'm wrong downvoter.

Comment: 2.how does the getLidCode() method work in this Constant Specific Class Body in Java 1.6,im accepting i dont know how this code of enum should work so i have posted this question

Comment: What does 'Constant Specific Class Body' mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you call a Constant Specific Class Body is what the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.9) refers to as *an optional class body for an enum constant*. It's implemented as an anonymous inner class that *extends* the outer, enclosing enum. So in your case, the enum constant `OVERWHELMING` will be of an anonymous inner type that extends `CoffeeSize`, and overrides the method `getLidCode()`. In pseudocode, the inner class looks something like this:

```
class CoffeeSize$1 extends CoffeeSize {
    @Override
    public String getLidCode() {
        return "A";
    }
}
```

Calling `getLidCode()` on either the constant `BIG` or `HUGE` will invoke the base enums implementation, whereas invoking the same method on `OVERWHELMING` will invoke the overriden version of the method, since `OVERWHELMING` is actually of a different type. To test, simply run code to invoke the `getLidCode()` of the different enum constants.

```
System.out.println(CoffeeSize.BIG.getLidCode());
System.out.println(CoffeeSize.HUGE.getLidCode());
System.out.println(CoffeeSize.OVERWHELMING.getLidCode());
```

Comment: excellent explanation SUPERB.Thanks so much Perception,im highly grateful to you.

Comment: i dont why others downvoted my question.i just needed an explanation :(,we all are here to help each other.Please share knowledge. Thanks again Perception

Comment: Perception,why have u voted to close it,it is a realistic question

Comment: @Deepak - this is a collaborative site, so I can't control the actions of others. Aka, I didn't vote to close but others might have.

Comment: Perception ,i have sent you an email.can u plz reply

Comment: Perception,i have written my code below.can you re check and upvote it since its working now.

Answer (score 3):

```
I have executed my answer,as below.Please correct me if im wrong.output is given.
```

Cheers :-))

```
public class EnumOverriddenExample {
enum CoffeeSize{               
      BIG(8),   
      HUGE(10),   
      OVERWHELMING(16){   

           public String getLidCode(){   
                return "A";   
           }   
      };

    CoffeeSize(int ounces){   
            this.ounces = ounces;   
    }

    private int ounces;   

    public int getOunces(){   
         return ounces;   
    }   

    public void setOunces(int ounces){   
         this.ounces=ounces;   
    }

    public String getLidCode(){   
            return "B";   
    }   
}  
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("CoffeeSize for BIG is "+EnumOverriddenExample.CoffeeSize.BIG.getLidCode());
    System.out.println("CoffeeSize for HUGE is "+EnumOverriddenExample.CoffeeSize.HUGE.getLidCode());
    System.out.println("CoffeeSize for OVERWHELMING is "+EnumOverriddenExample.CoffeeSize.OVERWHELMING.getLidCode());

    System.out.println("CoffeeSize for BIG is "+EnumOverriddenExample.CoffeeSize.BIG.getOunces());
    System.out.println("CoffeeSize for HUGE is "+EnumOverriddenExample.CoffeeSize.HUGE.getOunces());
    System.out.println("CoffeeSize for OVERWHELMING is "+EnumOverriddenExample.CoffeeSize.OVERWHELMING.getOunces());

}

}

Output is below
-----------------------------------
CoffeeSize for BIG is B --> returns "B"
CoffeeSize for HUGE is B -->returns "B"
CoffeeSize for OVERWHELMING is A--constant specific class body returns "A"
CoffeeSize for BIG is 8
CoffeeSize for HUGE is 10
CoffeeSize for OVERWHELMING is 16
------------------------------------
```