# enum - Non-static method cannot be referenced from non-static context

Tags: java, enums, compiler-errors

Error: java: non-static method a() cannot be referenced from a static context

I get this error on the following code.

```java
enum ENUM
{
  A()
  {
    {
      a();
    }
  }
  ,
  ;
  private void a()
  {}
}
```

I expect this to compile, but it doesn't.

Changing the access level modifier **private** from method a() to **any other** lets the code compile.

What may prevent this code from compiling?

Comment: There is no explicitly defined constructor in this code.

Comment: The error message you have in the title does not match the error message in the question. I already fixed it once, but you unfixed it. I suggest fixing it again.

Comment: The title looks like an obvious error. If you want to mislead people by making your title exactly the same as a famous error message except for one prefix, that's a ___ move. I'm gone.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442874/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-field-membervariable-with-priva.  That question has code that can't access a `private` variable from an enum constant with an anonymous subclass body.

Comment: also might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300816/enum-class-body-feature-in-java-1-6

Comment: @rgettman - Duplicate, isn't it? (And my, this is a strange dusty corner of Java).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It may be a dupe, but I'm not 100% sure, so I won't dupe-hammer it.

Comment: @rgettman - Me neither, and me neither. :-D I think it is, but don't know enums well enough to dupehammer.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer ... please drop me a comment, I am more than willing to put up a bounty here. But I have to admit, that at least the first linked other question ... it sounds right at least.

Answer (score 1):

You get this compile error because enum constants like *A* here are implicitly static. That's the reason we can use the enum constants like eg: *ENUM.A* in any other class. 
Thus we cannot call a non-static method from a static context. [Refer this documentation for more details on enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

Comment: But why does it compile if you change it to `public`?

Comment: Does it state why this only applies methods declared as private?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading. It's not limited to enums, or to initializer blocks or anything. The problem is simply that an anonymous inner class cannot access private methods from its enclosing class.

`private` states that sub-classes should not have visibility, and an anonymous inner class is a sub-class so it makes logical sense.

You can observe the same problem with this example:

```
class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo(){
            void bar() {
                a();
            }
        };
    }

    private void a(){ /* do nothing */  }
}
```

Comment: Why making `a()` static or `main()` non-static without changing visibility resolves the error?